# preg_match_all split conditional expression with special caracteres

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have data in this format:

```
Randomtext1(#random2#, #random4#) == 1 && Randomtext2 (ran dom) != 2 || #Randomtext3# > 3 && Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8) || Randomtext5  (Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8), random10) < Randomtext11()
```

with this:

```
preg_match_all("~\w+(?:\s*(\([^()]*+(?:(?1)[^()]*)*+\)))?~", $expression, $matches);
```

I obtain:

```
0 => 'Randomtext1(#random2#, #random4#)',
1 => '1',
2 => 'Randomtext2 (ran dom)',
3 => '2',
4 => 'Randomtext3',
5 => '3',
6 => 'Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8)',
7 => 'Randomtext5  (Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8), random10)',
8 => 'Randomtext11()',
```

But i want:

```
0 => 'Randomtext1(#random2#, #random4#)'
1 => '1'
2 => 'Randomtext2 (ran dom)'
3 => '2'
4 => '#Randomtext3#'
5 => '3',
6 => 'Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8)',
7 => 'Randomtext5  (Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8), random10)',
8 => 'Randomtext11()',
```

My problem, i lost `#` off element 4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\w` is `0-9a-zA-Z_`* you need to allow the `#` as well, you can use an alteration or a character class.

```
[#\w]+
```

or

```
(?:#|\w)+
```

Full example:

```
[#\w]+(?:\s*(\([^()]*+(?:(?1)[^()]*)*+\)))?
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/75eGQ

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/1PYvpO/1/

> \w stands for "word character". It always matches the ASCII characters [A-Za-z0-9_]. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits. In most flavors that support Unicode, \w includes many characters from other scripts. There is a lot of inconsistency about which characters are actually included. Letters and digits from alphabetic scripts and ideographs are generally included. Connector punctuation other than the underscore and numeric symbols that aren't digits may or may not be included. XML Schema and XPath even include all symbols in \w.

*https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: Question, what is the syntaxte if i want exclude Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8) ?

Comment: You could use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to skip. What is the pattern you are trying to remove, https://regex101.com/r/1PYvpO/2/

Comment: This syntaxe work for me "~(and|or)+(?:\s*(\([^()]*+(?:(?1)[^()]*)*+\)))+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[\w]+(?:\s*(\([^()]*+(?:(?1)[^()]*)*+\)))+|#([\[\] \w]+)#~u" but this is uptimised ?

Comment: I can probably be written another way but I'd need to know what the goal is. Also it is better to share a regex101 link, regex use a lot of characters that SO uses for formatting. I think your `&#91;` regex is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use this simpler pattern with `preg_split()`.  It's much easier on the eyes.

Code: ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ceda7af947c48ea7f6c0b8b74c3ad0a693a48d02)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pq8rT4/1))

```
$string='Randomtext1(#random2#, #random4#) == 1 && Randomtext2 (ran dom) != 2 || #Randomtext3# > 3 && Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8) || Randomtext5  (Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8), random10) < Randomtext11()';
var_export(preg_split('/ [=!&|<>]{1,2} /',$string));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Randomtext1(#random2#, #random4#)',
  1 => '1',
  2 => 'Randomtext2 (ran dom)',
  3 => '2',
  4 => '#Randomtext3#',
  5 => '3',
  6 => 'Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8)',
  7 => 'Randomtext5  (Randomtext4 (random5,random7,random8), random10)',
  8 => 'Randomtext11()',
)
```

This will match and split the string on `==`, `&&`, `!=`, `>`, `||`, `<` (there is one leading and one trailing space around the delimiting values -- hard to see in formatted text)